# Docker single process by container but how to use them together

Tags: docker, bioinformatics

I have standalone bioinformatic's tools I've put them into containers and they work fine. Now I have to put into container a tool that uses some of already dockerized tools. Not a real but understandable example: Docker A has *cat*, Docker B has *wc* and we have a third tool *catwc* that uses *cat* and *wc* in same combinations.

[Docker's best practice](http://docs.docker.com/engine/articles/dockerfile_best-practices/) suggests:
"In almost all cases, you should only run a single process in a single container. Decoupling applications into multiple containers makes it much easier to scale horizontally and reuse containers. If that service depends on another service, make use of container linking."

All solutions that I see are cumbersome.

- I either have to add *wc* && *cat* && *catwc* into one docker image while already have *wc* && *cat* in separate.  This mean I will have 2 best practice containers and one not.
- Do not dockerize *catwc* but do some bash wrappers to rename `docker run A cat "$@"` to *cat* and similar for *wc*.

In bioinformatics term I have a list of tools each one in separate docker image: bwa, bowtie, samtools, tabix, bgzip, bedGraphToBigWig, SHAPEIT2, VCFtools, Plink  and I have the tool that uses all of them [alea package](http://www.bcgsc.ca/platform/bioinfo/software/alea) which is java based, one solution that I use is to put everything into one image.

Are there other more manageable/space safe solutions?

Comment: Don't interpret "one process per container" guideline too literally. If the processes work together as a single application, then you should put them all in one container. For example, Postfix (an email transfer agent) use multiple processes, but they act as a single cohesive application, it'll not be reasonable to split it into per process containers. If you have a multi process application though, you need to take care with handling zombie processes and signals. Sometimes bash will suffice, but often you'd need a minimal init system like tini.

Answer (score 3):

It depends if this tools are running processes (like servers), or a simple libraries to be called (which, for instance, [bigWig](https://genome.ucsc.edu/goldenpath/help/bigWig.html) seems to be)

For librairies, you can containerize them in data volume containers that you can them mount in a final container with the option `--volumes-from`.
That means those containers don't run anything, they are just [`docker credate`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/create/)'d.

The other option is to build the image of the final container directly with those libraries [`COPY`](https://docs.docker.com/v1.8/reference/builder/#copy)'d in them.

For programs which are running a process, you can [linking them to the main container](https://docs.docker.com/v1.8/userguide/dockerlinks/) (as they are managed by the same docker daemon) with the [`--link` option](https://docs.docker.com/v1.8/userguide/dockerlinks/#communication-across-links).
That way, the main container can ping and access the other ones.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've learned about --volumes-from  maybe it will help. Actually, the tools that I have they are not libraries, but standalone executables like cat and wc or grep, but imagine that they are in different containers and they are big.

Comment: @AndreyKartashov if those executable are simply called, my answer stands: using `--volumes-from` will help grouping all containers into one.